# How to set up previous/next button in R markdown

Tags: html, r-markdown

I'm able to successfully set a table of contents using R markdown. However unable to find a way to provide buttons to navigate to previous/next page. I'd like it to be similar to this page : https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/rmarkdown-site.html#site_navigation

I started out with introducing a toc as explained the  rmarkdown book.https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#table-of-contents-1
Following are the YAML settings I'm using accordingly:

title: "Summary Report"
output:
html_document:
toc: true
toc_depth: 2
number_sections: true
df_print: paged
toc_float:
collapsed: true
smooth_scroll: true

However this does not still provide previous/next buttons the way its in the original link.
Wondering if there is an option that I'm missing that would enable this feature?

Comment: You need to proivde more details. What steps you have taken so far? What specific problem do you encounter?

Comment: Hi, I've provided more details. Hope that helps. I'm trying to understand if there are any options to enable previous/next buttons like in that original link.

Comment: You could try to use `runtime: shiny` in you YAML, and try something from here: [“Next” button in a R Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302682/next-button-in-a-r-shiny-app)

Comment: Thanks ViviG. Will take a look. Is there any equivalent option within R markdown? I ask because I'm new to shiny.

Comment: Hi Pradeep Ram. I found a nice solution using HTML. Let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set up previous/next buttons in R Markdown using HTML.

In my example I created four headings: "Previous/ next Button", "Render Document", "Look for the Reference for Each Page", and "Add the Buttons". They will be linked like this:

First page in my test: `href="#previousnext-button"`

Second page: `href="#render-document"`

Third: `href="#look-for-the-reference-for-each-page"`

fourth: `href="#add-the-buttons"`

They are referenced **starting with a hash tag, followed by the name of the heading (no space in between the hashtag and the heading title). Heading must be written in lowercase, connected by dashes, like this:** `"#the-name-of-the-heading-in-lowercase-separated-by-dashes`. **If you have a slash in the heading, ignored it, and type the two words separated by the slash as one**.

One example of buttons would look like this:

```
<ul class="pager"> <!--this is the style of the button-->
<li><a href="#">Back to Summary</a></li> <!--This button takes me to the table of contents-->
<li><a href="#render-document">Next</a></li> <!--This button takes me to the previous page-->
</ul>
```

`ul class="pager"` this is the style of the button.

`href="#Your-heading-reference"` will take you to the linked heading.

`href="#"`will take you back to the table of contents.

Here is an image of my test:

[image]

Comment: I dont see href links. I see references to class as shown in my example below:



<li class="tocify-item list-group-item active" data-unique="4_Analysis_:_" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="header-section-number">4</span>TEST.SECTION</li>

Also I plan to generate many reports using automation. So not sure if this idea will work in an automated setting. I was hoping more of a YAML setting like TOC example. Surprised that this setting is not available while TOC is.

I'm guessing bookdown package might offer some clues.

Comment: Yes, maybe bookdown is the way to go. You could create a new bookdown project and adapt its rmd file to suit your needs.  You can easily get a template (with the previous/back buttons you wish) by creating a new project in R studio -> New Directory -> then choose **Book Project using bookdown**.

Comment: Thanks ViviG!!. Appreciate your help and direction!

Comment: You're welcome! Let us know if it works! ( And feel free to answer your own question when you get your document up and going. [You can read about self-answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)